# Do calculation in the Makefile

Tags: shell, makefile

I got confused with Makefile. I am trying to run a simple command in the Makefile but it gives me the error "/bin/bash: line 3: :=: command not found". I am using shell to run this makefile

This is my part of my Makefile:

```
all:
   vlog Benchmarks/$(NAME)/Syn/*.v
   $(eval tux_number := 1)
   $(eval range := 1)
   $(eval ssh_log := 255)
   echo "Start Range: ${range}"
   echo "tux-number:  ${tux_number}"
   while [[ $$range -le 50 ]] ; do \
   ssh -l yazdanbakhsh tux-$(tux_number).cae.wisc.edu exit ; \
         echo "range:  ${range}" ; \
     eval $$range := $$((${range}+1)) ; \
done
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have := inside you eval?

Comment: ... and why are you using `eval` at all?

Comment: Because I want the assignment to happen instantly. (This is what I've heard) @ByronWhitlock

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: That only works for `make` variables, not `bash` variables.  What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: If I don't use eval it says that range: command not found!

Comment: I am trying to increate the range value by one!

Comment: I think you need to back to the basics on `make`, then.  Every line in a recipe is executed in its own subshell, so there's no way what you have there is going to work the way you expect.

Comment: I don't understand why some people just like to give negative.

Comment: You're confusing `make` macros and syntax with shell variables and syntax. And since each value is assigned in a sub-shell, it disappears after each invocation. In other words, the value of `$range` is not 1 after the `$(eval range := 1)` line. Please explain your purpose, so we can help you better. Based on your code snippet, it appears there is no reason to use `make` when a shell script would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

```
all:
    @range=1; \
  while [ $$range -le 10 ] ; \
  do echo Range: $$range; \
  let range=range+1 ; \
  done;
```

Note that the whitespace in front of `@range...` is the only TAB.

Comment: +1 for the point about the TAB. I suppose it is worth noting that GNU make is a bit "forgiving" and doesn't conform by allowing one leading TAB character (and only one) to be present after an escaped newline on a command line, according to its documentation. Apparently it simply notices it and removes it from the command line passed to the shell rather than treating it as the start of another command as it ought to.

Comment: @Chrono: GNU make is fully compliant with the POSIX standard and with historical make practice in that area.  I don't understand exactly what difference you're trying to describe, but no make program ever treats a line after a backslash/newline pair as the start of another make recipe line, regardless of which character it starts with.

Comment: My mistake. I misinterpreted what I was reading in the Single Unix Specification. It says that the tab will be discarded rather than included on the command line. So the point about the leading spaces in @Beta's answer appears more or less pointless since tab characters work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just to fix your obvious problems with `Makefile` syntax, here is an attempt at refactoring your attempt into valid code.

```
tux_number := 1
ssh_log := 255   # not used anywhere

all:
   vlog Benchmarks/$(NAME)/Syn/*.v
   echo "Start Range: 1"   # This is probably no longer very useful output
   echo "tux-number:  ${tux_number}"
   range=1; while [ $$range -le 50 ] ; do \
       ssh -l yazdanbakhsh tux-$(tux_number).cae.wisc.edu exit ; \
       echo "range:  $$range" ; \
       range=$$(expr "$$range + 1); \
   done
```

Notice how `tux_number` and `ssh_log` are Makefile variables, while `range` only exists in the shell which executes the `while` loop.  I have avoided the Bashisms in order to make this portable.  (If portability is not important, you might want to refactor it back to Bash syntax and use `for ((range=1; range<=50; range++)); do`... instead.)

Your use of `eval` is misguided.  As you can see, I simply lifted out the Makefile variables outside the recipe where they don't belong.  What you were doing was (1) have Make evaluate the expression `range := 1` (which evaluates to itself) and (2) use the output as a shell command in a recipe.  Since it's not a valid shell command, you got the syntax error from Bash.  Without further ado, I'll just take the easy way out here and say that `eval` is a complex subject, and until you get more experience with Make, it's probably just best to forget that it exists.

In order to properly make use of Make's facilities, I would make this parallelizable, i.e. split it up into 50 individual targets.  This is a bit clumsy (there's probably a better way to define `range` here), but at least it should illustrate a number of differences to your approach.  (If you don't insist on having `range` count up from 1, making it zero-based would make this a little less clumsy.  This exploits the fact that the empty string is harmless in a shell snippet, so we can use it instead of a zero prefix.  Again, this could be simplifed if you don't care about the human readability of the range index.)

```
digits := 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
deca   := "" 1 2 3 4
range  := $(filter-out ""0,$(foreach d,$(deca),$(foreach i,$(digits),$d$i))) 50
# Or, at the expense of an external process,
# range := $(shell perl -le 'print $$_ for 1..50')

.PHONY: all
all: $(patsubst %,ssh-%,$(range))

.PHONY: ssh-%
ssh-%:
    ssh -l yazdanbakhsh tux-$(tux_number).cae.wisc.edu exit
    echo "range: $*"
```

This can be run with something like `make -j 5` to execute these in parallel batches of five, for example.

Incidentally, the commented-out `$(shell ...)` call might be the actual answer to your question, if what you really wanted to do was to use Make to drive an external program to calculate something for you.